# SQL Server clause for random records

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column `[Star]` (`Integer`) that can have values of 1 or 2 or 3.

I have many records.

How can I select 100 records from my table that first select it's `[Star]` column are 3 value
then select `[Star]` with 2 value and finally select `[Star]` with 1 value?

Comment: thanks all,but my total returned records should be 100,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want first 3, the 2, then 1, but only the top 100 use:

```
 Select Top (100) * 
 from your_table 
 where [Star] in (1,2,3)
 Order by [Star] desc
```

If not please add some clarification/sample data and output to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Order by NEWID() will produce random results.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
            SELECT TOP (100) * FROM TABLE_NAME
            WHERE [Star] = 3
            ORDER BY NEWID()
      ) r3
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (
            SELECT TOP (100) * FROM TABLE_NAME
            WHERE [Star] = 2
            ORDER BY NEWID()
      ) r2
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (
            SELECT TOP (100) * FROM TABLE_NAME
            WHERE [Star] = 1
            ORDER BY NEWID()
      ) r3
```

If only a total of 100 random records are required you can adjust the TOP (n)

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 100 * from your_table where star = 1
union all 
select top 100 * from your_table where star = 2
union all 
select top 100 * from your_table where star = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM <TABLE> WHERE [Star] = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM <TABLE> WHERE [Star] = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM <TABLE> WHERE [Star] = 1
```